# Tidhttp taking too long for multimedia webpages

Tags: delphi, http, winsock, indy

Tidhttp.Get() appears to take a long time to return the html source at the url containing videos etc. Is there a way I can set it to ignore all images and videos? I only need the html source.

Comment: It gets just the HTML file, it doesn't download any other files. So no, there's no way to get just part of that HTML file (you may interrupt the download, but you'll get malformed HTML document).

Comment: Yes, the video content is not acknowledged in any way by TIdHTTP

Comment: However I myself have noticed that TIdHTTP does however take some abnormal time the first time it downloads a file, then you download it a second time and it's much faster...?

Comment: @JerryDodge I think the second time may be faster if server is sending the "keep-alive" header

Comment: Part of the delay could be due to `TIdHTTP` waiting extra time to make sure no unexpected data arrives at the end of the server's response, which some buggy servers do in some situations, particularly for HEAD and 3xx responses. To avoid that delay, make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, and then make sure the `hoWaitForUnexpectedData` flag is disabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That component already only downloads the HTML source. You can confirm by looking at the string or stream contents after the download is complete. Other resources linked to on the page are downloaded through additional resource requests, so if you only call `Get` once, you'll only get one resource (i.e., the main HTML content).

The cause of your perceived slowdown lies elsewhere.